# How to hide contents inside qoutes in C file/program

Tags: c, gcc

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define SHELLSCRIPT "\n\
#/bin/bash \n\
#this code can be seen;\n\
"
int main()
{
    puts("thiscodeishdden");
    system(SHELLSCRIPT);
        puts("done");
    return 0;
}
```

when i open the a.out file, i get this:

[image]

how am i able to hide this?

Comment: If you want to obfuscate the string then you need to generate it at runtime rather than compile time. The exact implementation needed would depend on how much effort you want to expend and how difficult you want it to be for anyone to reconstruct the string. For example, you could do a simple cipher of the string and decipher it at run time. Note that this is not true security but merely adding obscurity. Getting a truly secure solution is non-trivial.

Comment: is it possible you could give an example? I am new to C

Comment: Based on your immediate response it seems you haven't really taken much effort to at least attempt it yourself first. Please take the time to think about it and try to code something yourself. Write a program that takes a string, rotates each letter X places and prints the result. Take that output and replace `SHELLSCRIPT` with that string. Then recreate the original string by rotating X places in the other direction and pass that into `system`.

Comment: Just xor each byte in the string with a known sequence (using the `^` operator) before compilation. Then do the same when you need the string. A simple sequence like 1, 2, 3 will do for casual obfuscation.